# React application doesn't work properly on mobile using localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, localhost

I have a react application that works perfectly in localhost on a laptop. I tried to check the application from mobile how it looks. Pages get rendered but the database doesn't work on mobile. It doesn't send requests to the database. Is it because my application is in development?.

Comment: How are you sending the requests to the backend? Is it directly or through a proxy?

Comment: I exported ```http://localhost:5000/api``` from the config file imported it to the required file and sent as ```axios.post(`${api}/endPoint`)```

Comment: I don't understand this. Could you add the failing request request code & any proxy config to your question?

Answer (score 0):

In Laptop you might have accessed as localhost:3000 but in mobile using your laptop IP so CORS error might have occurred.

Comment: I have added CORS middleware also. Still it is not working.

Comment: Check the backend API if any restriction based on domain is applied. Ill also explore and let you know.

Comment: No I haven't applied any restriction. And also i have used cors middleware as app.use(cors()) that's it.